# zenity --auto-kill: Killing a subshell does not kill its child processes?

Tags: shell, kill, subshell, zenity

I am having a really hard time understanding the behaviour of `zenity --progress --auto-kill`. It appears to not kill its parent process' subprocesses but to detach them somehow.

Consider the following shell script `long-live-the-subshell.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
(
    echo sleeping...>&2;
    sleep 5;
    echo woke up >&2 
)  | zenity --progress --auto-close --auto-kill
```

To reproduce the mentioned behaviour:

- execute the script `sh long-live-the-subshell.sh`
- click **Cancel** on the progress bar
- wait another 5 seconds
- see that `woke up` is output to the terminal

Example output:

```
> sh long-live-the-subshell.sh 
sleeping...
Hangup
> woke up
```

The `Hangup` happens when you click **Cancel**. You then get your prompt back. However, after the `sleep 5` finishes, `woke up` is output to the terminal.

`ps jf` immediately after running the script:

```
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
20806 20825 20825 20825 pts/7     2391 Ss    1000   0:01 -zsh
20825  2391  2391 20825 pts/7     2391 S+    1000   0:00  \_ sh test.sh
 2391  2392  2391 20825 pts/7     2391 S+    1000   0:00      \_ sh test.sh
 2392  2394  2391 20825 pts/7     2391 S+    1000   0:00      |   \_ sleep 5
 2391  2393  2391 20825 pts/7     2391 Sl+   1000   0:00      \_ zenity --progress --auto-close --auto-kill
```

`ps jf` immediately after clicking **Cancel**:

```
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
 1179  2392  2391 20825 pts/7    20825 S     1000   0:00 sh test.sh
 2392  2394  2391 20825 pts/7    20825 S     1000   0:00  \_ sleep 5
```

Apparently, `zenity` kills its PPID (`2391` in this case) but somehow both of the other children of `2391` (`2392` and its only child `sleep` command `2394`) stay alive. Why? Shouldn't a `kill -1 2391` (which is obviously [what zenity does](https://github.com/GNOME/zenity/blob/4eddb202cafdcabc254aa941ad1348ff09372627/src/progress.c#L413)) kill also the children of `2391`?

Comment: What happens if you make the sub-shell into a compound statement instead, i.e. `{ echo...; sleep ...; echo ...; } | zenity...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell If I change the round braces to curly braces, the behaviour is the same. `woke up` is still output to the terminal.

Comment: Does really nobody have a clue to this? :-O

Comment: This may help... http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/331-linux-cancel-zenity-progress-dialog-right-way

Answer (score 0):

I have just found a nice way that works for me, and I think should work for most cases, using bash.

The idea is that you run Zenity in a container with a trap: when `zenity --auto-kill` sends a SIGHUP to the parent process, the parent process sends a SIGHUP to all processes in the same process group before dying.  So the key is calling Zenity like this:

```sh
{
    trap 'pkill -g 0' HUP
    zenity --progress --auto-kill
}
```

In the code below I show how I used this with a named pipe feeding Zenity, which makes things easier if you want the running process to produce data on standard output.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

...

zenityfifo=/tmp/zenityfifo$$
trap "rm --force $zenityfifo" EXIT

if [ -x /usr/bin/zenity -a "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    rm --force $zenityfifo
    mkfifo $zenityfifo
    ## The while loop is needed to keep the pipe blocking on read
    while read p < $zenityfifo; do echo $p; done | {
    trap 'pkill -g 0' HUP
    zenity --progress --title="resync" --auto-close --auto-kill
    } &
fi

while ...; do
    ...
    echo ... > $zenityfifo
done
```